# SQL Query optimization to avoid temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql

**The Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `T1` (
  `UserId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `FriendUserId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `IsDisplayed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Created` datetime NOT NULL,
  KEY `FriendUserId` (`FriendUserId`,`IsDisplayed`,`UserId`,`Created`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**The Query:**

```
SELECT `UserId`, `FriendUserId`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Created`) AS `Created`
FROM `T1` WHERE `FriendUserId` = 22
  AND `IsDisplayed` = 0
  GROUP BY `UserId`
  ORDER BY `Created`
```

**EXPLAIN result:**

```
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: T1
         type: ref
possible_keys: FriendUserId
          key: FriendUserId
      key_len: 5
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

**Question:**

How can I optimize it so that no temporary table is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you probably understand, the problem is that `GROUP BY` orders data by `UserId`, but the resulted set should be ordered by `Created`; thus, MySQL puts the output in a temporary table, sorts it and outputs.

The trick might be to force outputing distinct rows in the `Created` order at once.

The first that comes to my mind is something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  UserId,
  FriendUserId,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Created`) AS `Created`
FROM T1
WHERE FriendUserId = 22 AND IsDisplayed = 0
ORDER BY `Created`
```

and change the index to `(FriendUserId, IsDisplayed, Created, UserId)`.

Or another query with the same index:

```
SELECT
  UserId,
  FriendUserId,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Created`) AS `Created`
FROM T1
WHERE FriendUserId = 22 AND IsDisplayed = 0
GROUP BY `Created`, UserId
```

Comment: I don't understand... it is no more ordered by created.... with the modifications you made...

Answer (score 12):

MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) says:

> Temporary tables can be created under conditions such as these:
>
> If there is an `ORDER BY` clause and a different `GROUP BY` clause,
>   or if the `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` contains columns from tables other than
>   the first table in the join queue, a temporary table is created.

So, you can only avoid of using temporary table only by removing `order by Created`