# MySQL compare, count and order by

Tags: mysql, sql, count, compare, sql-order-by

I am having trouble with understanding how to solve a seemingly simple problem of sorting results.

I want to compare how many other users like the same fruits as like the user with `ID` 1, a count who has the most matches and display the results in descending order.

users:

```
1  jack
2  john
3  jim
```

fruits:

```
id, title
1   apple
2   banana
3   orange
4   pear
5   mango
```

relations: 2 indexes (`user_id`, `fruit_id`) and (`fruit_id`, `user_id`)

```
user_id, fruit_id
1        1
1        2
1        5
2        1
2        2
2        4
3        3
3        1
```

expected results: (comparing with Jack's favourite fruits (`user_id=1`))

```
user_id,  count
1         3
2         2
3         1
```

Query:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM relations
WHERE fruit_id IN (SELECT fruit_id  FROM relations WHERE user_id=1) 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count>=2
```

More "optimized" query:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM relations r
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM relations WHERE user_id=1 and r.fruit_id=fruit_id)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count>=2
```

2 is the minimum number of matches. (required for the future)

explain:

```
id  select_type         table       type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref                 rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             r           index   NULL            uid     8           NULL                15      Using where; Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  relations   eq_ref  xox,uid         xox     8           r.relations,const   1       Using where; Using index
```

Everything is working fine, until I try to use `ORDER BY count DESC`

Then I see:  Using temporary; Using filesort

I don't want to use temporary tables or filesort. Because in the future, the database should be under high load.

I know, this is how `SQL` is defined and how it operates. But I can not figure out how to do it in other way? Without temporary tables and filesort.

I need to show the users who has the most matches first.

Please, help me out.

**UPDATE:**

I did some tests with the query from Walker Farrow (which is still uses a filesort).

```
20,000 rows -  avg  0.05 seconds
120,000             0.20 sec.
1,100,000           2.9 sec.
```

disappointing results.

It would be possible to change the tables structure, but, with such a counting and sorting - I don't know how.

Is there any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: Well, you can shift the sorting mechanism in programming language part if that's not a problem.

Comment: Yes, it would be easy if there were a small number of results. The problem is the number of users - the number of matches. Displaying data over multiple pages...

Comment: Well, maybe this answer might help you [SQL Query optimization to avoid temporary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896271/sql-query-optimization-to-avoid-temporary-table).

Comment: There are already two indexes (user_id,fruit_id) & (fruit_id,user_id) on fruits table on two columns. I don't understand how it can help. *count* is dynamic data. Could you please explain?

Comment: i meant indexes on *relations* table

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this would be to create a subquery and then order by in the outer-query, something like this:

```
select *
from (
     SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM relations r
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM relations WHERE user_id=1 and r.fruit_id=fruit_id)
     GROUP BY user_id
     HAVING count(*)>=2
     ) x
order by count desc
```

Also, I don't know why you need to add `exists`. Can you just say the following:

```
select *
from (
     SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM relations r
     WHERE user_id=1 
     GROUP BY user_id
     HAVING count(*)>=2
     ) x
order by count desc
```

?

I am not sure, maybe I am missing something. HOpe that helps!

Comment: I have a question about the first query, 

explain:
`id  select_type  table     type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  PRIMARY  <derived2> ALL  NULL   NULL  NULL  NULL  3  Using filesort
2  DERIVED  r     index  NULL   uid  8  NULL  15  Using where; Using index
3  D. SUBQUERY  relations     eq_ref  xox,uid   xox  8  r.relations 1  Using index`

So it using "filesort" on the results (3 rows). Can this "using filesort" be a problem in the future, when DB will grow, let say 50 million rows?

Comment: About the second query. It is wrong, because it only counts John's favorite fruits (id:1). 
We need to compare them with the rest - who have similar.

Here ive found how to optimize my first query (with IN operator)
[Optimizing Subqueries with EXISTS Strategy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html)